# How to show a graph is not Hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose you are given a graph $G$ with the properties that $G$ is 3-regular, $v_G = 10$ where $v_G$ is the number of vertices in $G$, and girth$(G) \geq 5$. How can you tell that $G$ is not Hamiltonian?

So far, I have been trying to figure it out by looking at the Petersen graph, which I know is not Hamiltonian via a result in a book I have. The Petersen graph has $v_G = 10$ and girth$(G) = 5$, but I don't know how this relates to being non-Hamiltonian.

Comment: It's not true for all graphs satisfying these conditions. For example, a 5-cycle fused with a 7-cycle such that they share two neighbor nodes will have 10 vertices and girth 5, but still be nicely Hamiltonian.

Comment: Oops, upon reading my post again I realize I forgot to add the property that $G$ was 3-regular. My bad! But nice counterexample for the original post.

Comment: What is $\nu_G$? Explaining your notation (even if it is sort of standard) *never* hurts.

Comment: $v_G$ is the number of vertices of $G$. I have edited my post to add this explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the *only* 3-regular graph with exactly 10 vertices and girth $\ge 5$ *is* the Petersen graph. So the fact that *all* such graphs are non-Hamiltonian is simply because the Petersen graph happens to be.

First suppose the girth is 5 exactly: Start by drawing the 5-cycle. Because the graph is 3-regular, each of the vertices in the 5-cycle must have an additional neighbor, and these neighbors must all be new and distinct because otherwise the girth requirement would be violated. But that means that we now know *all* of the vertices, and the only way we can give each of the new vertices two more edges without creating 4-cycles is to connect them exactly as the Petersen graph.

If the girth is 6 or more, a similar argument quickly produces a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer! I am curious. Does a proof exist that does not require referencing the Petersen graph? (Even if it is the only graph satisfying such requirements) That is, is there some general criteria that would force a graph to be non-Hamiltonian based solely on the number of vertices/girth/regularness?

Comment: @user41419: I have trouble imagining there could be any such criteria, except to the extent they force the graph to be one of a few particular graphs, as in this case. So it's a trick question!

Answer (score 4):

I know of a theorem that states "Let $G$ be a graph. If there is a set $S$ of vertices such that $G-S$ has more than $|S|$ components, then $G$ has no Hamiltonian cycle." It can be proved by contradiction.

I'm assuming that by 'Hamiltonian' you mean 'Hamiltonian Cycle', as that's what we learned in school. Also, a component is a set of vertices with no neighbors outside of the set.

Comment: I think your theorem can be proven without contradiction. This is actually a contrapositive of the theorem: Let $G$ be a simple Hamiltonian graph. Then, for each $S\subseteq V(G),$ the number of connected components in $G-S$ is at most $|S|$.

Comment: Since $G$ is Hamiltonian, it has a Hamiltonian cycle $C$. Since $C$ is a cycle, the number of connected components in $C-S$ is at most $|S|$. Since $C$ is a subgraph of $G$ and $V(C)=V(G)$ and $E(C)\subseteq E(G), G-S$ contains at most the number of connected components of $C-S$. Hence $G-S$ has at most $|S|$ connected components.